# Get/set number value to localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, storage, local

I'm trying to use local storage to store a number so that it stays even if i refresh or revisit the page, but whenever i refresh the return value is 0.

I know that it's probably a really easy fix that I can't figure out but i would very much appreciate an answer to this beginners (probably) easy question.

In case you were wondering this is for a star rating system.

HTML:

```
<p id="r1"></p>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x1;
    x1 = +localStorage.getItem("x1");
    $("#r1").html("Your rating: " + x1);

    $("#rating1 span").click(function() {
        x1 = 5 - $(this).index();
        $("#r1").html("Your rating: " + x1);
    });

    localStorage.setItem("x1", x1);
});
```

Comment: Just to be clear `localStorage.getItem(x1)` is the same as `localStorage.getItem(undefined)`

Comment: Because the variable `x1` is declared, but has no value, it's undefined, and you pass that variable to `getItem`. You probably wanted to quote it as a string instead, `+localStorage.getItem("x1");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First problem is that you're not providing the name of the local storage item when you retrieve it with `getItem`, that should be `localStorage.getItem("x1")`.

The second problem is that you're calling `setItem()` when the page is loaded, not when the user clicks on the rating, so it's not using the rating that the user selects.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x1;
    x1 = +localStorage.getItem("x1");
    $("#r1").html("Your rating: " + x1);

    $("#rating1 span").click(function() {
        var x1 = 5 - $(this).index();
        $("#r1").html("Your rating: " + x1);
        localStorage.setItem("x1", x1);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently you are requesting the local storage value for the key `undefined` because `x1` has no value. If you change `x1` to a string you will then get the value for the key `"x1"` if it exists.

So your code would become:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var x1 = localStorage.getItem("x1");

    $("#r1").html("Your rating: " + x1);

    $("#rating1 span").click(function() {
        x1 = 5 - $(this).index();
        $("#r1").html("Your rating: " + x1);
        localStorage.setItem("x1", x1);
    });


});
```

your `localStorage.setItem("x1", x1);` is correct, but in the wrong spot, it needs to be inside the click event block.

Comment: Well both your and Barmar's answer worked so thank you very much for the help!! appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

This is because x1 is undefined. So what you are essentially doing is localStorage.getItem(undefined). This returns null, and since you have a plus it's converting null to 0.

```
 +null == 0; // true
```

Comment: even if i change var x1; to var x1 = 0; i get the same result

Comment: @random1234 You need to give a name to the localStorage item.

Comment: It should be `localStorage.getItem("x1")`

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused, it still isn't working. @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

It appears you may be a bit confused as to how the localStorage methods works. Basically you need two things: a key and a value you wish to assign to it. I'll give you a brief example of how it works.

```js
const key = 'taco';
let value = 'sauce';

localStorage  // {se:fkey: "c6d8756477bc8eb22494f28a5bbc3afc,1464967104", length: 1}

// Now let's say I want to save this to local storage. This is how.
localStorage.setItem(key, value);

localStorage // {se:fkey: "c6d8756477bc8eb22494f28a5bbc3afc,1464967104", taco: "sauce", length: 2}  . As you can see it is now in localStorage.

// Now let's say we want to retrieve what we set from localStorage.
localStorage.getItem(key); // 'sauce'
```

Hope that helps.